# `path must start with the project source root` error in ng serve

Tags: angular-cli-v6

I want to use `jquery` and `bootstrap` in my `Angular-CLI` project. The `Angular-CLI` project is in `project/ui` directory and the `jquery` and `bootstrap` files are in `project/public/...` path. I am trying to refer to the `jquery` and `bootstrap` files as follows in `angular.json` but on running `ng serve` in `project/ui` directory, I am getting error - `The ./../public/images/favicon.png asset path must start with the project source root`. What am I doing wrong?

The snippet of `angular.json` is

```
"projects": {
    "ui": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "./../public/images/favicon.png"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./../public/stylesheets/common/css-reset.css",
              "./../public/stylesheets/common/common-styles.css",
              "./../public/stylesheets/common/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./../public/javascripts/common/vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.js",
              "./../public/javascripts/common/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"
            ]
          },
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//file - angular.json

"assets": [
   "src/assets",
   "src/favicon.ico"    //This worked for me.
]
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/asset-configuration.md#writing-assets-outside-of-dist - Link to additional context behind this

Answer (score 0):

> The ./../public/images/favicon.png asset path must start with the
>   project source root

The error states that the path for the favicon.png must start with the project source root.
For a default angular project, this is the src folder.

As stated in the answer above, make sure your path is absolute and starts at src.